# Unknown * in numpy.random function

Tags: python, numpy

I was studying [this link](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/) and this is the code .

```
 U1 = np.random.rand(*H1.shape) < p # first dropout mask
```

Why does it fail when I try to do this?

```
import numpy
numpy.random.rand(*1) < 2
```

I understand that the `rand()` function takes in a number which is why I am confused that the code is supposed to work.

Comment: @reviewers, Sorry about edit after dupe. Didn't see it was dupe closed.

Comment: I don't think this is a dup question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `*` unpacks a tuple into multiple input arguments. The code is creating a random matrix the same shape as `H1` using the `shape` attribute (which is a tuple) as the dimension inputs to `np.random.rand`.

You can do this with any tuple

```
np.random.rand(*(2,3))     # The same as np.random.rand(2,3)
# Creates a 2 x 3 array
```

You are trying to unpack an integer which is going to fail.